# kubernetes : unable to join a node

Tags: kubernetes

I have created a master and am trying to join a node to create a cluster. When I try the join command I get the below error. Both the nodes are on the same network. The error message indicates that no routing exist to the host. I'm not sure how to establish a route to the host. Any help is appreciated.

```
 sudo kubeadm join --token d23afe.14fde99cd03def7e 192.168.178.24:6443 --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:6a5e2674825e683bbdfe9bab512b03c556bcf89d8648317a64372bb44746bb39
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
        [WARNING SystemVerification]: docker version is greater than the most recently validated version. Docker version: 18.02.0-ce. Max validated version: 17.03
        [WARNING FileExisting-crictl]: crictl not found in system path
[discovery] Trying to connect to API Server "192.168.178.24:6443"
[discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "https://192.168.178.24:6443"
[discovery] Failed to request cluster info, will try again: [Get https://192.168.178.24:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info: dial tcp 192.168.178.24:6443: getsockopt: no route to host]
```

Here's the output of sudo route. Unfortunately, I have little knowledge to troubleshoot from this output

Here's the output of

```
`sudo route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
10.32.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.240.0.0     U     0      0        0 weave
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     205    0        0 datapath
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     210    0        0 vethwe-datapath
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     211    0        0 vethwe-bridge
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     212    0        0 vxlan-6784
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

`

Comment: It looks like you do not have the proper route to the host. The way to check it is by executing `sudo route`. There you should see the routes available to the instance.

Comment: I don't see any route to the master instance

Comment: Are you able to execute `ping 192.168.178.24`?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to identify the issue. The issue was with the weave net plugin. I did a tear down and reinstalled the plugin. I was then able to join the node. Thanks all for your suggestions.